# Can you have code executed when you change selection in a dropdown menu?

Tags: java, drop-down-menu

I have a combobox. When I select option A I call a method which instantiates an object. I then call one of the objects methods. What I am struggling to do is have another method of the object called when I change to a different selection. I would like this to be executed before the code of the new selection. Is there a simple and easy way to do this?

Here is an overview of what I mean:

```
    public void dropdown(ItemSelectable is, int state){

     switch(selectedString(is))
           {
           case "A": if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED){option1();}
           break;               
           case "B": if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED){option2();}
           break;
           case "C": if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED){option3();}
           break;
           }
}

public void option1(){

 someclass objectname = new someclass();
 objectname.somemethod1();

 //To be executed on deselection of A
 objectname.somemethod2();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try use MenuSelected and MenuDeselected

```
private void A_MenuSelected(javax.swing.event.MenuEvent evt)
{                                
    System.out.println("a");
}                               

private void A_MenuDeselected(javax.swing.event.MenuEvent evt)
{                                  
    System.out.println("b");
}
```